# Is there any difference between Observable and Future.get

Tags: rx-java, hystrix

Any difference between the two?

```
String r1 = new GoogleCommand().queue().get();
```

and

```
Observable<String> gResp = new GoogleCommand().observe();
String r1 = gResp.toBlockingObservable().single();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the response from Twitter:

`observe()` eagerly executes and caches whereas `toObservable()` is lazy until subscribe and doesn't add caching.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what you meant by your question but I understood that you were asking about "future vs observable" while your answer was "observe() vs toObservable".. I was looking for "future vs observable" (in the case where the response will be one object rather than a stream).. any answer to that?